# How to show the cardinality of nonisometric compact metric spaces is the continuum

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, compactness

It is asserted in *A Course in Metric Geometry* by Burago, Burago, Ivanov that

> there can be no more than continuum of mutually nonisometric compact spaces

How is this proven?

Its clear that there must be at least a continuum of mutually nonisometric compact spaces, i.e. $([0,\alpha], d_{\mathbb{R}})$ for $\alpha>0$ are a family of nonisometric metric spaces, but I don't know enough set theory to have any ideas how to bound the cardinality from above. A first guess was that the fact that compact metric spaces are totally bounded should be useful?

Comment: Here are some steps - Each (infinite) compact contains a countable dense set. Order it -- $(x_1,...)$. 
Consider an infinite matrix $d(x_i,x_j)$.
One can recover the metric $d$ from such a matrix.  

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think "compact" can be even weakened here to "separable and complete" (and regarding your first guess, total boundedness is essentially used to prove that compact implies separable).  Here's a sketch: any such space is determined, up to isometry, by the restriction of the metric to a countable dense subset.  Thus the number of such isometry classes is bounded above by the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}}$, which is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, which is the continuum.

Answer (score 7):

Since a compact metric space is in particular separable, its type of isometry is determined by a dense countable subspace. There are continuum many distances on , say $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 5):

Extend Qiaochu's deleted comment.  Compact metric spaces are separable, can be isometrically embedded as closed subsets of the separable metric space $C[0,1]$.  This space has continuum many closed subsets.

Comment: Very nice     !

Comment: Sorry, could someone provide more details? How does the embedding work? Also how do you know that there are at most a continuum of closed subsets?

Comment: @OtisChodosh See Wikipedia article [Urysohn universal space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urysohn_universal_space) or [Corollary 5.18](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hcqm4_lW4EkC&pg=PA145) in *Functional Analysis and Infinite-Dimensional Geometry* by Fabian et al.